# RPy2 - ggplot2 - how to modify legend?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, legend, rpy2

How can I modify the legend of a plot built using ggplot2 with rpy2?
My plot is the following:

```
plot_2 = (ggplot2.ggplot(second_dt) +
          ggplot2.aes_string(x='timestamp', y='diff_percentage') +
          ggplot2.geom_point() +
          ggplot2.geom_line())
```

and I would like to modify the position of the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was sufficient to do as follows:

```
plot_2 = (ggplot2.ggplot(second_dt) +
          ggplot2.aes_string(x='timestamp', y='diff_percentage') +
          ggplot2.geom_point() +
          ggplot2.geom_line() +
          ggplot2.theme(**{'legend.position': <position>}))
```